# I can't log in after removing the user login left bar

Tags: blocks, users

I removed the user login block on the left of my default drupal instalation (7.21) and now i can't login.

When i try: mysite/drupal/?q=admin 
It gives me "access denid".

I Don't feel like reinstalling my drupal just for this there has to be a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply go to `http://yoursite/user` or if you don't have clean url enabled `http://yoursite/?q=user`